# Geolocation really slow what i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, geolocation

I try to get location from my browser but it's really slow form 5s to 8s. I dont know why it's so slow

```
const getUserGeolocation = (): Promise<{latitude: number, longitude: number}> => new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async pos => {
        resolve({latitude: pos.coords.latitude, longitude: pos.coords.longitude})
    })
})
const {latitude, longitude} = await getUserGeolocation()
```

Answer (score 1):

May be it's just because of **too many** use of **async**. remove both of the async keyword from your code. I think that will help you to execute the code faster.

Comment: I cannot remove async from the second function because it's return a new Promise . but It's not faster as expected :(

Comment: Both your uses of the `async` keyword are unnecessary. Try removing them and leave the `await` keyword only. Async does not speed anything up, it is all run on a single thread.